# SQL Миграция через Phinx. Ошибка при миграции, ругается на id записи

Tags: php, mysql, sql, миграция, cakephp

Задача:
В таблице есть поле содержащие тело статьи(текст). В этом тексте есть ссылки старого формата, нужно пройтись регуляркой и заменить формат. К сожалению на проекте версия MySQL 5.7, а функции для регулярной замены (REGEXP_REPLACE) была добавлена в 8.0. Ещё нужно учитывать что на проекте все работы с БД происходят через миграции Phinx(из Cake).

Было принято решение сделать выборку по всем статьям(их +- 6к) и перебрать тексты статьи и заменить ссылки силами php, в цикле.

Вроде бы всё должно работать но почему то БД ругается на id.
Пометка: 27 id - это id первой записи в таблице.

[image: Ошибка при выполнении миграции]

```
public function up()
{
    $rows = $this->fetchAll("SELECT id, body from blogposts");

    foreach ($rows as $post )
    {
        $post['body'] = preg_replace('/sustainability/(\d+/\d+/\d+)/(.+)', '/sustainability/$2', $post['body']);
        $postId = $post['id'];
        $postBody = $post['body'];
        $this->query( "UPDATE blogposts SET body = $postBody  WHERE id = $postId ")->save();
    }
}
```

Прошу подсказать и разобраться в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: $postBody - строка. Строковый литерал должен быть обрамлён кавычками.

Comment: при наличии отличного orm в кейке писать прямые апдейты несколько странно. сначала решите вопрос с регулярным выражением, там отсутствуют начальный и конечный разделитель, так что оно вряд ли у вас работает.

Comment: @teran Самого cake нет. Только Миграции из него. Поэтому QB тоже нет... Такой вот проект попался

Comment: @Akina спасибо. Прошло без ошибки. Вот только поле body стало пустым...

Answer (score 0):

обычно такое делается в виде

```
$bpt = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('BlogPosts');
$items = $bpt->find('all')->select(['id', 'body'])->toArray();
foreach($items as $p){
     $p->body = preg_replace("/..../", "...", $p->body);
}
$pbt->saveAll($items);
```

при этом учесть, что регулярное выражение должно иметь вид `/expr/flags`, то есть имеет ограничители в начале и конце. То есть не `/sustainability/(\d+/\d+/\d+)/(.+)` а `~/sustainability/(\d+/\d+/\d+)/(.+)~`. (Обычно в качестве ограничителей выступают `/`, но поскольку эти символы у вас используются, то лучше заменить на `~` или `#`, в основном используют эти 3 варианта)

для таких целей имхо лучше не миграции использовать а Command сгенерить.

[Документация к phinx](https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/migrations.html#creating-an-update-query), велит делать примерно следующим образом

```
$rows = $this->fetchAll("SELECT id, body from blogposts WHERE body like '%/sustainability/%'");
$builder = $this->getQueryBuilder();
foreach($rows as $row){
    $body = ...;
    if(!$changed) continue;

    $builder->update('blogposts')
            ->set(['body', $body])
            ->where(['id' => $row->id)
            ->execute();
    
}
```

Однако, да, `getQueryBuilder` в конечном итоге сводится к `PdoAdapter::getDecoaratedConnection`, возвращающий экземпляр `\Cake\DatabaseConnection`.

Интересно, что в этой ситуации методы `execute()` и `query()` имеют только один параметр - текст запроса и не позволяют передавать параметры.

Возможно, альтернативой будет получить нижележащий экземпляр PDO и выполнить запросы через привычные подготовленные выражения.
Получить вроде можно через `$this->getAdapter()->getConnection()`.
А дальше обычные `$connection->prepare()`  и `execute()` с передачей параметров.

Comment: В phix так к сожалению нельзя. А если я добавляю ограничители, то вылезает другая ошибка                 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the ri  
  ght syntax to use near '[picture url="/files/image_2016/10/kachestvo-tovarova-v-podhodah.jpg" title="" s' at line 1

Comment: Почему то только вырезка из 1 строки в БД

Comment: Ссылки этого формата есть не в каждой статье

Comment: @Animov тогда чезе queryBuilder как напиано в документации к phinx - https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/migrations.html#creating-an-update-query `$vuilder->update(...)->set('body', $body)->where(...)`

Comment: Вот в том то и дело что queryBuilde поставляется с Cake. А у меня его нет. Только пакет для миграций Phinx

Comment: @Animov немного дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить.

```
$rows = $this->fetchAll("SELECT id, body from blogposts");

    foreach ($rows as $post )
    {
        $post['body'] = preg_replace('~/sustainability/(\d+/\d+/\d+)/(.+)~', '/sustainability/$2', $post['body']);
        $post['body'] = addslashes($post['body']);
        $postId =  $post['id'];
        $postBody = $post['body'];
        $this->execute( "UPDATE blogposts SET body = '$postBody'  WHERE id = $postId ");
```

Добавил обработку экранирования, т.к в статьях содержаться апострофы свойственные для английского языка.

```
$post['body'] = addslashes($post['body']);
```

Так же в запросе на UPDATE переменную содержащую текст необходимо обромить в ковычки.

```
$this->execute("UPDATE blogposts SET body = '$postBody'  WHERE id = $postId")
```